# construction of entity type in query is not allowed

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Any idea what I could be doing wrong. I am trying to return object of Type AppRole by linking 2 tables. But I get error Explicit construction of entity type 'AppRole' in query is not allowed. How can I get object of type AppRole which meets the condition.

```
AppRole RoleName = (from role in dbContext.AppRoles
                                            join user in dbContext.AppUsers on role.RoleID equals user.RoleID
                                            where user.UserName.Contains(userNameDL)
                                            select new AppRole
                                            {
                                                RoleID = role.RoleID,
                                                RoleName = role.RoleName,
                                                Description = role.Description,
                                                Status = role.Status,
                                                UpdateDate = role.UpdateDate
                                            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You just need to do `select role).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly create that object as you just learned the hardway.  When you call `select new AppRole{}` you are explicitly creating a new one, which is unnecessary, since you already have a bunch of `AppRole` objects in your query.  You just want to pull one out of the collection.

Instead you can just do this:

```
AppRole RoleName = (from role in dbContext.AppRoles
                    join user in dbContext.AppUsers on role.RoleID equals user.RoleID
                    where user.UserName.Contains(userNameDL)
                    select role)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

`select new` or `.Select()` (with a lambda) is for making a projection, usually to a different datatype.  Since you are running the query on already created `AppRole` objects there is no need for this and instead we can just return the first that matches.

As to *WHY* you cannot do this it's because when you perform the linq-to-sql query (this is also the case in linq-to-entities) it will translate the code into SQL, however the object creation cannot be translated into SQL, so you will get an error message like you just experienced.

Comment: msdn say: [A query expression must begin with a from clause and must end with a select or group clause.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384065.aspx)

Comment: @Grundy You are absolutely correct, just updated my answer.  It's been awhile since since I've used this style for making queries.  I usually use the lambda style.  Just updated my answer.